# Unity blue line indicator mean?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

[image]

Can someone tell me what those blue line indicators mean beside the variables Top Location and Bottom Location? I am using Unity Game Engine and these are variables used in a script attached to a gameObject. I can't seem to find anything about it so far.

Comment: It is prefab overwrites

Answer (score 5):

It means the value for the corresponding property has been changed from the default value.  This can also occur if the object in question is a prefab where the current value is different from the original prefab.